# Filter the games that were released in different years in different platforms (R)

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a csv file with video games info. The columns are

```
| Rank | Name | Platform | Year | Genre | Publisher | NA_Sales | EU_Sales | JP_Sales | Other_Sales | Global_Sales |
```

Note: Sales are in millions.

One row would be:

```
259, Asteroids, 2600, 1980, Shooter, Atari, 4, 0.26, 0, 0.05, 4.31
```

I am trying to filter for those games that were released in different platforms in different years, for example, Mario Bros was released for DS and Wii in 1996 and 2000.

I have tried to create a function that uses two `for loops` to try and find games that have the same name, but I don't seem to get it right. I have also tried to group by `Name, Year, Platform` and I get it wrong too.

I can't get this done and it's really frustrating, any help would be welcomed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please share some reproducible data along with expected outcome

Comment: Do names match exactly when published on new platforms?

Comment: Once the data are in a dataframe, `dplyr::distinct` should do the trick.

Comment: Something like `library(dplyr)` `your_data %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(n_distinct(Platform) > 1)` should get you started. Hard to be more helpful without sample input and corresponding desired output.

Comment: I misspelled the question. The question is “Find the games that were released in different years in different platforms”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
dat %>%
  group_by(Name) %>%
  filter(n_distinct(Platform, Year) > 1) %>%
  ungroup()
```

## data.table

```r
library(data.table)
as.data.table(dat)[, .SD[uniqueN(interaction(Platform, Year)) > 1,], by = .(Name)]
```

## base R

```r
ind <- ave(interaction(dat$Platform, dat$Year), dat$Name, FUN = function(z) length(unique(z)) > 1)
```

If your `Platform` column is `integer`, then use

```r
dat[ind > 0,]
## or
dat[ind == 1L,]
```

If, however, your `Platform` is `character`, then you'll need

```r
dat[ind == "TRUE",]
```

This is because `stats::ave`'s return value is always the same class as its first argument, `dat$Platform` here. Even if the inner `FUN`ction produces logical or something else, it is always coerced. (Since `ave` uses `` `split<-` `` which reassigns the updated `x` back into the original vector, the coercing acts by default, not necessarily by-design.)

**Edited** to include `Year` in the determination.

Comment: I misspelled the question, the question is “Find the games that were released in different years in different platforms”. Also, the Platform column is string, and thank you I will be trying this now.

Comment: Okay, replace all checks for uniqueness in `Name` with `Year`.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Typo, see my edit. Include `Platform` _and_ `Year`.